# Azure blob storage and CDN

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

Can anyone help me how could I upload file and image on `Azure blob storage` through `Azure CDN`?
is there have an idea about `Azure CDN`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't upload to the CDN directly. You should upload to the Storage and then it will be [under CDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-create-new-endpoint/).
However, it is possible to integrate web service/cloud service with CDN like [that](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-cloud-service-with-cdn/).